# Java Generics Casting with extended Type

Tags: java, generics, casting, extends

I want to cast a generic type which extends the class 'BoostItem' to its base class 'BoostItem' and then call its constructor (with an integer). How can I achieve this? T must always extend BoostItem therefore it should always be possible to cast the Argument boostFood to class BoostItem, right?
What am I missing here..?

```
public <T extends BoostItem> void addBoostFood(Class<T> boostFood){
        try {
            // How to cast boostFood to BoostItem
           // Call constructor of BoostItem with Parameter int
           ((BoostItem)boostFood).newInstance(5); //Doesnt work


        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

**------------- EDIT**
Resulting Source Code (Looks ugly and I don't think I will use it as it's too slow and unflexible)

```
  public <T extends BoostItem> void addBoostFood(Class<T> boostFood){
            try {
                Constructor[] ctors = boostFood.getDeclaredConstructors();
                for(Constructor c : ctors) {
                    Type[] types = c.getGenericParameterTypes();
                    boolean isRightCon = true;
                    for(Type t : types){
                         if(t != Integer.class)
                               isRightCon = false;                                    
                    }
                    if(isRightCon) 
                        gFoodBoosterList.add((BoostItem) c.newInstance(new Integer(5)));
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have attempted to cast the `Class` object `boostFood` as a `BoostItem` object, not the result of calling `newInstance`.

First, you can move the cast outside the parentheses, so that the result of the method call is casted.  But that should be unnecessary, because you can always assign a subclass object to a superclass reference.

Second, the [`newInstance` method in `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) doesn't take any arguments.  This is a convenience method for class that contain no-argument constructors.  You will need to get the appropriate `Constructor` object from the `Class` via `getDeclaredConstructor`, passing in `int.class` as the parameter type (or `Integer.class` as the case may be).  Then you can call [`Constructor`'s `newInstance` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-), which does take parameters.